# Find all angles $0\le v<360^\circ$ with $\sin3v=\sin39^\circ$

Tags: trigonometry

> Find all angles $0\le v<360^\circ$ with $\sin3v=\sin39^\circ$

I have so far come up with
$$v=(120\pi n+13π)/180\\
v =(120\pi n+47π)/180$$
Is this correct at all?

And how do I know which value I should use for $n$?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Draw a graph. It might help.

Comment: You have the right idea, but you should avoid mixing radians and degrees. Since the problem calls for degree measure, you can write $v = 13° + 120° n$ or $v = 47° + 120° n$. You can find the correct values of $n$ quickly by trial and error.

Comment: So if my calculations are corerct, all possible angles v are 13°, 47°, 133°, 167°, 253°, 287°?

Comment: looks like you have some confusion between radian measurements and degree measurements.  The question requests an answer in degrees.  $\pi$ is a factor that does not belong in this problem.

Comment: Your last comment indeed shows the correct answer.

Comment: I am very confused regarding radians overall. For example, if I'm looking at a range of angles between -π and π, does that mean 360°?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Let $x=3v$. If $v$ must be between $0^\circ$ and $360^\circ$, then $x=3v$ must be between $0^\circ$ and $1080^\circ$.

Now, find all values of $x$ between $0^\circ$ and $1080^\circ$ such that $$\sin x = \sin 39^\circ$$

For this step, I recommend that you draw the [unit circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle#Trigonometric_functions_on_the_unit_circle) and sketch how the sine behaves as you travel around the circle.

---

Helpful tidbit $1$:

> Adding $360^\circ$ to $x$ does not change the value of $\sin x$, since this is equivalent to going all the way around the unit circle. Note that this corresponds to adding $120^\circ$ to $v$.

Helpful tidbit $2$:

> $x$ and $180^\circ - x$ have the same sine. This corresponds to the fact that $3v$ and $3(60^\circ - v)$ have the same sine.

---

Finally, divide each of these possible values of $x$ by $3$ to get the possibilities for $v$.

Comment: I still don't know if my calculations were correct, but if so I tried with n=0, 1, 2. Then I get that the angles would be 13°, 47°, 133°, 167°, 253°, 287°. Is this correct?

Comment: That looks completely correct to me. One thing: I would encourage finding the $6$ values of $x$ and then dividing by $3$ at the very end, instead of explicitly solving for $v$. I think it is less error-prone. But that's just a nitpick, any method is good if it works :)

Comment: The values for $v$ correspond to values for $x$: $$x = 39^\circ, 141^\circ, (39 + 360)^\circ, (141+360)^\circ, (39 + 720)^\circ, (141+720)^\circ$$

To me, it seems easier to check that *those* values are correct (as opposed to the values of $v$), since they are the angles whose $\sin$ should be the same

Answer (score 0):

We have either $3v=360^\circ n+39^\circ$ where $n$ is any integer

$\implies v=120^\circ n+13^\circ$

We need $0\le120^\circ n+13^\circ<360^\circ\iff 0\le n<3$

OR  $3v=360^\circ n+(180-39)^\circ$ where $n$ is any integer

$\implies v=120^\circ n+47^\circ$

Can you take it from here?